# Check if key is just pressed using sdl.GetKeyboardState() in sdl2-go binding

Tags: go, input, keyboard, sdl-2

I'm trying to create an `isKeyJustPressed()` function in go using the `sdl2-go` binding. I'm doing this by checking if the previous keyboard state is unpressed, and the current one is I.E. `prevKeyBoardState[keyCode] == 0 && sdl.GetKeyboardState()[keyCode] == 1`

My problem is that when I use this the `prevKeyBoardState[keyCode]` only returns 1 when the current state also returns 1. This is odd as I make 100% sure that I update the previous keyboard state *after* I check if it's pressed as so:

```
if isKeyJustPressed(g.prevKeyboardState, keySpace) {
    log.Println("The space key was pressed")
}

g.prevKeyboardState = sdl.GetKeyboardState()
```

As you can see it is update after checking for the keypress, so I don't understand why it's not returning 1 until the current keyboard does. Is this because SDL2 doesn't update the keyboard or something else? Also here is the code for checking the keypress incase it helps

```
func isKeyJustPressed(prevKeyBoardState []uint8, keyCode int) bool {
    return prevKeyBoardState[keyCode] == 0 && sdl.GetKeyboardState()[keyCode] == 1
}
```